Permission denied on openHAB image startup with Podman
I'm facing a problem while trying to run a container based on the image "openhab:4.3.0-debian" on Podman v5.3.1 on Fedora v41 Workstation.
I created a dedicated "openhab" user and group (with UID=9001 and GID=9001) and set up three configuration directories to be mounted as volumes inside the container.
Here are the steps I followed:
sudo useradd -r -s /sbin/nologin openhab
sudo usermod -a -G openhab openhab
sudo mkdir -p /opt/openhab/{conf,userdata,addons}
sudo chown -R openhab:openhab /opt/openhab

Then, I ran the container with the following command:
podman run \
        --name openhab \
        --net=host \
        -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
        -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome:/etc/timezone:ro \
        -v /opt/openhab/conf:/openhab/conf \
        -v /opt/openhab/userdata:/openhab/userdata \
        -v /opt/openhab/addons:/openhab/addons \
        -e USER_ID=9001 \
        -e GROUP_ID=9001 \
        -e CRYPTO_POLICY=unlimited \
        openhab/openhab:4.3.0-debian

However, I am getting a "permission denied" error, see the following log:
user@fedora:/opt$ podman run         --name openhab         --net=host         -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro         -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome:/etc/timezone:ro         -v /opt/openhab/conf:/openhab/conf         -v /opt/openhab/userdata:/openhab/userdata         -v /opt/openhab/addons:/openhab/addons         -e USER_ID=9001         -e GROUP_ID=9001         -e CRYPTO_POLICY=unlimited         openhab/openhab:4.3.0-debian
+ IFS='
    '
++ find /usr/lib/jvm -maxdepth 1 -name '*jdk*' -type d
+ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
+ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
+ '[' unlimited = unlimited ']'
+ echo 'Configuring Java unlimited strength cryptography policy...'
Configuring Java unlimited strength cryptography policy...
+ sed -i 's/^crypto.policy=limited/crypto.policy=unlimited/' /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/conf/security/java.security
+ capsh --print
+ grep -E Current:.+,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,.+
+ rm -f '/var/lock/LCK..*'
+ rm -f /openhab/userdata/tmp/instances/instance.properties
+ NEW_USER_ID=9001
+ NEW_GROUP_ID=9001
Starting with openhab user id: 9001 and group id: 9001
+ echo 'Starting with openhab user id: 9001 and group id: 9001'
+ id -u openhab
++ getent group 9001
Create group openhab with id 9001
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ echo 'Create group openhab with id 9001'
+ groupadd -g 9001 openhab
Create user openhab with id 9001
+ echo 'Create user openhab with id 9001'
+ adduser -u 9001 --disabled-password --gecos '' --home /openhab --gid 9001 openhab
adduser: Warning: The home dir /openhab you specified already exists.
Adding user `openhab' ...
Adding new user `openhab' (9001) with group `openhab (9001)' ...
adduser: The home directory `/openhab' already exists.  Not touching this directory.
adduser: Warning: The home directory `/openhab' does not belong to the user you are currently creating.
Adding new user `openhab' to supplemental / extra groups `users' ...
Adding user `openhab' to group `users' ...
+ groupadd -g 11 audio2
+ groupadd -g 14 uucp2
+ groupadd -g 16 dialout2
+ groupadd -g 17 audio3
+ groupadd -g 18 dialout3
+ groupadd -g 32 uucp3
+ groupadd -g 63 audio4
+ groupadd -g 490 dialout4
+ groupadd -g 492 audio5
+ groupadd -g 997 gpio
+ adduser openhab audio
Adding user `openhab' to group `audio' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab audio2
Adding user `openhab' to group `audio2' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab audio3
Adding user `openhab' to group `audio3' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab audio4
Adding user `openhab' to group `audio4' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab audio5
Adding user `openhab' to group `audio5' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab dialout
Adding user `openhab' to group `dialout' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab dialout2
Adding user `openhab' to group `dialout2' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab dialout3
Adding user `openhab' to group `dialout3' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab dialout4
Adding user `openhab' to group `dialout4' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab gpio
Adding user `openhab' to group `gpio' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab uucp
Adding user `openhab' to group `uucp' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab uucp2
Adding user `openhab' to group `uucp2' ...
Done.
+ adduser openhab uucp3
Adding user `openhab' to group `uucp3' ...
Done.
+ initialize_volume /openhab/conf /openhab/dist/conf
+ volume=/openhab/conf
+ source=/openhab/dist/conf
++ ls -A /openhab/conf
+ '[' -z '' ']'
Initializing empty volume /openhab/conf ...
+ echo 'Initializing empty volume /openhab/conf ...'
+ cp -av /openhab/dist/conf/. /openhab/conf/
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./html': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./icons': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./items': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./persistence': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./rules': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./scripts': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./services': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./sitemaps': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./sounds': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./tags': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./things': Permission denied
cp: cannot create directory '/openhab/conf/./transform': Permission denied
cp: preserving times for '/openhab/conf/.': Permission denied


When I run the command with Docker (using sudo docker run with the same parameters), the container starts correctly.
What is missing in my Podman command to get the container up and running with no errors?
Thanks in advance for your support!

You will need to check (a) which user-id is running that cp command inside the container and also (b) what user ids are on the contents of /openhab/dist/conf/*.

Hi @RichardHuxton, (a) from the log I can see "+ echo 'Create user openhab with id 9001' + adduser -u 9001 --disabled-password --gecos '' --home /openhab --gid 9001 openhab", is it sufficient to say that is the user with uid 9001 that tries to run the "cp" command? (b) how can I check that? Thanks for your help!
